Can supavisor use different database rather than it's locally installed database
The installation doc mentioned a docker Postgres container to use the supavisor to store it's tenant data/metadata.
Is it possible to use a local database for storing tenants data instead of docker container?
Anyone have idea on this?
I need to setup a local database to use the supavisor for it's usage

Yes, this is possible:
create database my_pooler_db;

Then you can connect with PSQL like this:
psql postgres://postgres.your_project:pass123@aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/my_pooler_db

You should see:
psql (16.3 (Homebrew), server 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

my_pooler_db=>

